# How to correctly use the col2im function?

Tags: matlab, matrix

This function is confusing to use, and it always gives me an error:

> To RESHAPE the number of elements must not change.

That's my code:

```
im=im2col(zeros(300,300),[3 3]);
im(:,9)=ones(9,1);
im=col2im(im,[3 3],[300 300]);
```

Basically, this code just gets the block at index 6, replaces it with ones, and reassembles it back into the original image. What's wrong with this code?

Comment: Please show us what the desired end result is. Perhaps somebody could suggest a better way to achieve it w/o using "confusing" functions. This may be a case of an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/). Also, the error you mentioned is **not** the error your code gives - in my case (R2019b) it's: _Unable to perform assignment because the size of the left side is 9-by-1 and the size of the right side is 6-by-1._.

Comment: Also, the provided code crashes at the second line, since you have `9x1` on the left side, and `6x1` on the right side - and, that's a different error than you mentioned.

Comment: Sorry! That was typo, it's 3x3, edited.

Comment: Have a look at the [`distinct`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/col2im.html) parameter.

Comment: That will gives you a new error of `The column size of b not consistent with BLK2COL size.`

Answer (score 2):

It seems you want to create distinct blocks from your input array, change single blocks, and rearrange them. (Your target size is the same as your input array size.) So, you must use the `distinct` parameter in both, `im2col` as well as `col2im`:

```matlab
blk_size = [3, 3];
im = zeros(9, 9)
temp = im2col(im, blk_size, 'distinct');
temp(:, 3) = ones(prod(blk_size), 1);
im2 = col2im(temp, [3 3], size(im), 'distinct')
```

Output:

```
im =
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0

im2 =
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

When using `im2col` with the `sliding` parameter, which is also the default, if no parameter is set at all, there'll be a lot more columns in the result than can be rearranged to the input array size, cf. the [Tips](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/im2col.html#mw_6a85cf70-fc9d-429c-934b-610312afd96a) section on `im2col`.

Hope that helps!